# is there a way to add and remove controls from a form to another without the controls being deleted/GCed?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one form called:

```
MyControlContainerForm ccf
```

and a main form called:

```
SolidForm sf
```

and I am adding all the controls inside an instance of `new MyControlContainerForm ()` to `SolidForm`, using:

```
sf.Controls.Add ( Control )
```

but when I remove them using:

```
sf.Controls.Remove ( Control )
```

they are gone from `MyControlContainerForm` instance as well.

Why? And how do I prevent this?

I want to be able to add `MyControlContainerForm` controls whenever I want, without initializing `MyControlContainerForm` every time, just once.

Comment: Create a Static member of type Control on the SolidForm type and have it shared across instances might be one option to try.

Comment: Thanks, what's the Control type is gonna store? You mean all the controls from ccf?

Comment: are you really developed imdb

Comment: No, I didn't. I am a semi-pro actor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is happening is not that you're removing the controls from form2, but rather that you're adding them. Controls can't be shared between forms. If you look at the reflected code of the form2.Controls.Add() on the Control Collection enumerator, we can see what's happening here:

```
...
  if (value.parent == this.owner)
        {
            value.SendToBack();
        }
        else
        {
            if (value.parent != null)
            {
                value.parent.Controls.Remove(value);
            }
            base.InnerList.Add(value);
...
```

As you can see here it check the parent of the incoming control, if it's not the owner of the collection, then it simply runs a value.parent.controls.Remove(value) to strip the control from it's originating form, so it can be added to the current one.

Answer (score 1):

Controls are not intended to be on 2 Forms at the same time. Im surprised you got way with that, probably because you do not Show MyControlContainerForm .

Note that Control has a Parent property (= in who's Controls collection am I?), singular.

#### Edit:

In fact, when button1 is on panel1, it is part of panel1.Controls. But the statement

```
panel2.Controls.Add(button1);
```

**removes** button1 from panel1.Controls.

---

You can use a `List<Control>` as a store. That would also keep them alive just fine.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try it. But why doesn't my references keep them alive. I just use MyControlContainerForm ccf and instance it, and add the controls from ccf. But the List should preserve the references?

Comment: Yes, the list will keep the references as long as you keep the list somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Henk. But I still want them to be added to this list from ccf. I guess that's possible. I will let you know.

Comment: No, a Control can't be on 2 Forms at once. So either make a new ccf each time or 'save' the Controls in a List.

Comment: Thanks, but the idea of making the controls on different forms is for layout purposes. So I did it and gathered them in a list, so now it works.